# Declarar váriavel recebendo elemento de um vetor dentro de um for é uma boa pratica ou é desnecessário?

Tags: javascript, declaração-de-variável

//código 1

```
var pacientes = document.querySelectorAll(".paciente");

for(var i = 0; i < pacientes.length; i++){
    var paciente = pacientes[i]; //linha desnecessária
    paciente.classList.remove("invisivel");
}
```

//Código 2

```
var pacientes = document.querySelectorAll(".paciente");

for(var i = 0; i < pacientes.length; i++){
    pacientes[i].classList.remove("invisivel");
}
```

Acima tem dois trechos de código diferente, peguem um código em JS em que vi que essa prática era comum em vários trechos do código, declarar uma variável recebendo o o elemento do *array* `var paciente = pacientes[i];`, porém acho bem mais prático já colocar o elemento do *array* em sua posição e removê-lo da classe: `pacientes[i].classList.remove("invisivel");`, come vemos no segundo código.

Como o código estava bem estruturado fiquei na duvida se isso seria uma boa prática (se sim, por que? pois não consigo enxergar boa prática nisso), ou seria somente para deixar o código mais didático.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essencialmente não faz diferença ter uma variável extra embora a declaração em si pode ser um pouco pior em algumas versões de alguns navegadores. Particularmente eu não crio variáveis que não são necessárias, então eu faria o segundo código.

Eu sei que muito programador cria variáveis porque aprenderam assim e não sabem que pode ser sem a variável.

Existe caso que criar a variável pode documentar melhor o código, desde que dê uma bom nome para ela, mas não é o caso.

Que tal usar assim:

```
for (let paciente of pacientes) {
    paciente.classList.remove("invisivel");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/VariableDeclaration..js).

Se puder usar este [`for` do ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) acaba com a dúvida.

Comment: Entendo, minha linha de pensamento é como a sua, não gosto de criar variáveis desnecessárias.

Answer (score 2):

Há ligeiras implicações de performance quando se declaram variáveis, mas na maior parte dos casos é preferível código fácil de ler. Dá uma olhada [a este teste](https://jsperf.com/declaring-variables-inside-loops/4), e repara como o último exemplo é mais lento.

Com ES6 e o `let` pode fazer ainda mais sentido usar isso, pois assim a variável fica restrita ao bloco do for:

```js
var a, b;
for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    var a = i;
    let b = i;
}

console.log(a, b); // 9, undefined
```

Se tiveres um loop com muiiiiiiitas iterações, e não precisares de declarar a varíavel, faz sem essa declaração. Se não for o caso dá prioridade à facilidade de leitura e manutenção de código.